# UI Change in Back Ground Thread

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a function and this function send http request in back Ground Thread
when request is excute and complete i have some line of code to make UI Change but when fragment pause the app crash Because the function cant make UI Change when fragment pause i dont now what i must do for solve this

```
    val url = "BASE_DIR/example"
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val code = client.newCall(request).execute().code()

    if (code == 200) {
        
        fragment.requireActivity().runOnUiThread { 
            fragment.refresh.isRefreshing = false
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to send a message to the UI thread is with a `Handler`

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
    // do whatever
}
```

or you have the usual `postDelayed` methods etc. So you can update `fragment` without it needing to be attached to an `Activity`, which is probably better than just doing a null check on `getActivity` (the fragment might just be temporarily detached, so you still want to update its state so you don't "lose" the result).

If you don't mind losing the result, because you're treating the detached fragment as dead so it doesn't need to be updated, then the null check like in @rahat's answer is the simplest way to do it. Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be!

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference - > i got this EXCEPTION when fragment pause :(

Comment: That's nothing to do with what you're doing here (or the code you posted)! You're doing ``findViewById`` on a ``View`` that doesn't exist anymore - either do it in ``onCreate`` (or ``onCreateView``) and assign it to a variable, or use null safety with ``view?.findViewById`` and null-check the result before you do anything with it

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
fragment.getActivity()?.runOnUiThread { 
            fragment.refresh?.isRefreshing = false
        }
```

The issue is when the fragment is detached the [requireActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireActivity())

will throw `IllegalStateException` so since it is not associated with any `activity`, but `getActivity()` returns null if it is not associated with any `activity`, so with null safe call you can do it safely.

Comment: i try this but i got this EXCEPTION : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference - > its happen when navigate to another fragment before function finish